# What utilities do I need to begin android development on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, development, cubieboard

I already would work by some Cortex-A boards(for instance Cubieboard, Marsboard,...)
I've already started working with integrated circuits:

- Cubieboard
- Marsboard

I've been directed to learn linux, but this poses a problem. I don't have enough experience with it - like the changes between distributions. In my case, I'd like to use Android and Ubuntu - but I don't want to scope my knowledge to just Cortex-A boards. Recently I've been turned on to [rawbrawb](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11861/rawbrawb) in this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82213/help-for-find-camera-datasheet-or-interface-to-st32f103) that I can use Android for modules.

To sum it up:

1. What toolchain(s) will I **need** to work with Android on Ubuntu?
2. Is the following package suitable for android experimentation?  [Free Download Android OS 4.1.1 Jelly Bean](http://www.mygadgetsinfo.com/2012/08/free-download-android-os-411-jelly-bean.html)

Comment: that site looks pretty sketchy from the url. you should get info from the official Android site, android.com. that will tell you what you need, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/index.html) has everything you need to get started with Android development.

You need the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to develop Java applications; [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is generally recommended but not mandatory as an IDE.

You need the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to develop native applications in C or C++.

Both the SDK and the NDK are self-contained. You don't need any other development tools.

If you want to learn Android development, you don't need a board: the SDK comes with an emulator. If you're interested in low-level programming, you do need a board. You'll need an Android image to go with it. Google does not provide a universal Android image: you need one with the right drivers for your board. Typically you can get it from the manufacturer or from a community built around that manufacturer.

For low-level programming, you may be better off with a plain Linux than with Android. Ubuntu provides a cross-compilation toolchain for ARM: [gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi) and friends. [Other toolchains exist](http://elinux.org/Toolchains).